# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable on Azure?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, azure

I have a web app running in `Azure`, in which I'm trying to implement a third party `dll` which requires the installation of [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523). The problem is that I don't know how to install this in an `Azure WorkerRole` instance. Is it possible?

Or would I have to resort to using a VM? (Which I really don't want to).

Comment: Do you actually mean to "use a third party dll"?

Answer (score 1):

Startup tasks are designed for this scenario.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180155.aspx

For this, I would recommend using a "simple" startup task.  The ExecutionContext is probably going to need to be "elevated".